# How do I input a number and make that number display a symbol that amount of times?

Tags: python, algorithm, input, symbols

I am trying to make a program which takes a number as input, and the outputs this many as # symbols.
I got as far as -

```
Hash = input(“Enter a number? “)
```

But I dont know how to use that input to display the # that many times.
E.g.

```
Enter a number? 6
(printed)######
```

Can anyone tell me how I can do this?

Comment: You can do: `'#' * number`

Comment: A good start would be to start reading the excellent [*documentation*](https://docs.python.org/3/)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude why not [this documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/)?

Comment: I'm guessing this is a homework assignment to teach you loops. Go read about loops in Python, as SPD said, the documentation is a good place to start reading about loops.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to print `n` times the symbol `#`:

```
print('#'*n)
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember to indent this properly
You can use:

```
Hash=int(input("Please enter a number: "))  
for each in hash:  
    print("#")
```

Comment: maybe you mean `for each in xrange(hash)` or simply `range(hash)` in python 3.x, but for this type of approach is better to use `_` which is a disposable variable like `for _ in range(hash)`

Answer (score 0):

This simple code will give the result you want.
`n=int(input(“Enter a number? “))
print('#'*n)`